# How to prevent OverFlow of the Trailing widget using Column widget to occupy all the children elements inside of a ListTile widget?

Tags: flutter

How to prevent OverFlow of the Trailing widget using Column widget to occupy all the children elements inside of a ListTile widget ?
Thanks and appreiciate you help.

```
    body: ListView.builder(
        restorationId: 'sampleItemListView',
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final item = items[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey.shade400,
              height: 200,
              child: ListTile(
                  isThreeLine: true,
                  leading: const CircleAvatar(
                    // Display the Flutter Logo image asset.
                    foregroundImage:
                        AssetImage('assets/images/flutter_logo.png'),
                  ),
                  title: Text('Title ${item.id}'),
                  subtitle: Text('Subtitle ${item.id}'),
```

**How to expand the column in the Trailing component of the
ListTile to prevent Overflow?**

```
                  trailing: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.emoji_emotions,
                        color: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.emoji_emotions,
                        color: Colors.orange,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.emoji_emotions,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),


                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.restorablePushNamed(
                      context,
                      SampleItemDetailsView.routeName,
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

[image]

ERROR:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 16 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case there r many answers like

```
  1: ListTile( visualDensity: VisualDensity(vertical: 4))
```

```
  2: ListTile( 
        trailing: FittedBox(
            child: Column( children: const [Icon(),Icon(),Icon()]),
            ),
     )
```

** But best solution in my opinion, In such extensive cases use "Row" than "ListTile" it gives u way more control over ur UI widgets.