# Flutter: Unable to get the Expanded widget to work with trailing property for my list to render properly on the screen

Tags: flutter, rendering, expanded

I need the Expanded widget to co-operate with the trailing property otherwise all the ListTile contents is squished to the far-right of the screen.

However, I get the following error message and not sure how to fix the issue.

> Error message:

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library > =======================================================
> The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to >   a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type >
> BoxParentData.
>
> Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget.
>
> Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _ListTile widget.

```
children: List.generate(
          10,
          (index) => ListTile(
            key: keys[index],
            trailing: Expanded(
                child: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                  index: index,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(index.toString()),
                      Text('   The index is {$index.toString()}'),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: there r some height issues on ListTile. u can check this que & ans [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499193/12519864 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think **trailing** accept **Expanded**

instead of trailing and Expanded you can use **title** and **Row** to achieve the design

```
  ListTile(
                title: ReorderableDragStartListener(
                  index:index,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(index.toString()),
                      Text('   The index is {index.toString()}'),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much magesh magi!